# Nothing appears after reading user input on fortran

Tags: if-statement, fortran

For some reason I don't have anything appearing after the user inputs the limits for the upper and lower limit of my table. What I want to do is make it so that if the user has an upper limit or lower limit that exceeds the bounds of -10,200 the user has to re-input the limits. If it does not exceed the limit, then it will reveal a table/matrix showing the numbers from the upper to lower limit in addition to two columns, one that converts it to Fahrenheit and another converting it to kelvin.

My do loop functions normally on its own, but after adding in the if statements nothing appears after the user inputs the upper and lower limits.. what am i doing wrong ?

```
program Lab03b
implicit none
integer::i,k,l
real, dimension(22)::matrix
Write (*,*) 'Please enter the upper and lower limit of your table in centigrade where the 
lower&
& and the upper limit is within -10 to 200. (separate with comma)'
Read (*,*) k,l
if (k>=abs(-10)) then
if (l<=abs(200)) then
    write (*,*) '  Centigrade', '       Farenheit', '        Kelvin'
    do i=k,l
            matrix(i)=i
            print*, i,32.0+1.8*i,i+273.15
    end do
    print*, 'your table has',k+1,'rows and 3 columns'
else 
print*, 'Your lower limit is less than -10 or your upper limit is greater than 200, please try again' 
end if
end if
  end program Lab03b
```

Comment: What do you think happens in this program when the user set k=53 and l=600?

Comment: There is a lot wrong with your attempt. You may find it helpful to write down in words what steps you want to take to solve the problem. When you have that you can worry about writing code.

Comment: You need to loop back if the values of k and l are not in the range. Take a look a the until-loops here: https://www.tat.physik.uni-tuebingen.de/~kley/lehre/ftn77/tutorial/loops.html

Comment: Note that the conditional `k>=abs(-10)` is true only when k is larger than or equal to 10. As stated in your question: _"...bounds of -10,200..."_ you should delete **both** `abs` functions in your conditionals.